# Import of "node-fetch" in TypeScript fails quietly, variables of same type can't be assigned to each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm playing with a little bit of TypeScript as a Node/TS newbie, and would like to import *node-fetch* into my tiny project (which I'm editing in VSCode). I'm experimenting with a wrapper I found for the promises returned by *fetch()*. My code looks something like this:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

interface HttpResponse<T> extends Response {
    parsedBody?: T;
}

async function http<T>(
    requestInfo: RequestInfo,
    requestInit?: RequestInit
): Promise<HttpResponse<T>> {
    let response : HttpResponse<T>;
    try {
        response = await fetch( requestInfo, requestInit);
        response.parsedBody = await response.json();
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);            
        }
        return response;
    } catch (ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}

function post<T>(
    path: string,
    body: any,
    headers?: any
): T | undefined {
    let value: T | undefined;

    (async () => {
        return http<T>(path,
            { method: "post", body: JSON.stringify(body), headers: headers })
    })().then(respData => {
        console.log(respData);
        value = respData.parsedBody;
    });
    return value;
};


export default class SimpleClient {
    readonly url: string = 'https://foo.bar.baz.com/';

    constructor(token: string) {
        type ClientResponse = {
            data: {
                client_response: string
            }
        } | undefined;

        const value: ClientResponse = post<ClientResponse>(this.url, { "token": token });
        if (value === undefined) {
            throw new Error("No client token returned");
        }
        this.clientToken = value.data.client_response;
    }
```

In *index.ts* :

```
import SimpleClient from "./simple_client.js";

const token : string = 'super secret token (shhhhh!)';

let sClient = new SimpleClient(token);
```

But when I run *tsc*, then fun begins:

```
$ npx tsc
src/vault_client.ts:13:9 - error TS2322: Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'HttpResponse<T>'.
  The types of 'clone().body' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'ReadableStream | null' is not assignable to type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null'.
      Type 'ReadableStream' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>': locked, cancel, getReader, pipeThrough, and 2 more.

13         response = await fetch( requestInfo, requestInit);
           ~~~~~~~~

src/simple_client.ts:13:33 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'RequestInfo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("/Users/ackthpfft/Documents/dev/local/simple_client/node_modules/node-fetch/@types/index").RequestInfo'.
  Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'.
    Type 'Request' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': size, buffer

13         response = await fetch( requestInfo, requestInit);
```

Even weirder is what happens when I comment out the *import* statement: *tsc* compiles the code, but execution fails with a *ReferenceError* because *fetch* cannot be found.
I would have expected IntelliSense to have caught that.

My *packages.json* is thus:

```
{
  "name": "simple-client",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "npx concurrently -k -n compiler,nodemon -c yellow,blue  \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon -w dist -q dist/index.js\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ackthpfft",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "findup-sync": "^5.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Does anyone have suggestions? I expected that something this simple would have worked right out of the box.

Comment: could you show the rest of the function? and how you are calling it?

Comment: Done with edit above. Now, I'm not interested just yet in comments about coding style yet. They're nice to have, but they don't answer this question. So please, first things first. Thanks.